# JTabbedPane with autoscrolling Tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtabbedpane, autoscroll

If I use this function more than once in the programm the tabs stop autoscrolling. Autoscrolling woks with one Tab:

```
protected JTextArea addTab(String name){
    JTextArea tab = new JTextArea();
    tab.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(tab);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    this.tabPane.add(name, scroller);
    return tab;
}
```

Comment: please isn't about scrolling with JTextArea instead ???

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question buy you can check out [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for general information about scrolling when using a JTextArea.